# Most efficient way of calling (in) a new thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

Have the following, rather trivial intention in an JFX application: When a key is pressed on the keyboard and thus a handle(event ev) method is called, I want that something happens in a different, otherwise unused thread.

So far I found to have three options:

Either creating the new thread directly in the handle:

```
public void handle(KeyEvent ke)
{
  new Thread(() -> {
    // THE CODE
    }).start();
  }
}
```

Or I launch a different thread at programm start looking about like this:

```
public void run()
{
  while(true)
  {
    if (triggered)
    {
      // THE CODE
    }
  }
}
```

and then in the handle() method, I just set the "triggered" field to true.

The third method would be to create as many instances of a class extending "Thread" as needed to be executed in parallel and use their start() function in the handle().

Well, from what I see, the former method has a significant overhead due to thread creation.

The second method is pointlessly requiring CPU resources 99.9% of the time.
That can only be weakened by adding a sleep() to the loop.

And the third method appears to be quite similar to the first as most resources are allocated when called start(), or am I wrong?
That method also has the downside to have to keep several instances in memmory because I can not preddict how many will be called in parallel.

What solution would you suggest?
Are there other possibilities?

Huge thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest adding the task to an `ExecutorService` This works as a background thread pool and is idle when not used. The threads in it are reused however to improve efficiency. You can use a cached thread pool if you don't know how many threads at once you will need.

```
static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

public void handle(KeyEvent ke)
{
    executor.execute(() -> {
        // THE CODE
    });
}
```

or

```
public void handle(KeyEvent ke)
{
    executor.execute(this::task1);
}

void task1() 
{
    // THE CODE
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), so you can avoid:

- repeatly creating new thread
- unnecessarily check `triggered` status

Like this:

```
ExecutorService executor = executors.newcachedthreadpool();

public void handle(KeyEvent ke)
{
  Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
      void run() {
          // code
      }
  }
  executor.execute(runnable);
}
```

Comment: I suggest learning to use lambdas as most IDEs now have auto-refactorings to use them. Also Java 10 is the current version ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yeah, I am trying. It looks very cool. My company is use jdk7 : (

Comment: With the faster release cycle it's going to be hard for some companies to stay current. btw Java 9 is End Of Public Support and Java 10 will end in 5 months. :P

Answer (score 1):

You could either use a JavaFX `Service` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) or create a `Task` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) that you submit manually with a new `Thread` or using an `Executor`, for example from `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`.

The alternatives are covered quite well in https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm.

Based on what you have written I would probably go for the `Service`, but both alternatives should work.